# jaxb2-basics-runtime NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE when upgrading from 0.6.4 to 1.11.1

Tags: java, jaxb2

I'm upgrading from jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.64.0 to jaxb2-basics-runtime-1.11.1.

When my generated Object trys to use the generated toString method....

```
public String toString() {
    final ToStringStrategy strategy = JAXBToStringStrategy.INSTANCE;
    final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    append(null, buffer, strategy);
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

It throws an NoSuchFieldError

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at com.bean.RequestIDCommonData.toString(RequestIDCommonData.java:147)
```

I know on the classpath I only have jaxb2-basics-runtime-1.11.1.jar.

I know that when I check where the JAXBToStringStrategy is loaded from, it shows jaxb2-basics-runtime-1.11.1.jar

```
Class klass = JAXBToStringStrategy.class;
java.net.URL location = klass.getResource('/' + klass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
System.out.print(location);
```

I know the I'm compiling with JDK 1.7 and I've tested that Tomcat is running with JDK 7.

```
 Double.parseDouble(System.getProperty("java.specification.version"));
 1.7
```

I know that if I remote debug into Tomcat from Eclipse and I execute the following command, it gives me an Object instance.

```
ToStringStrategy strategy = JAXBToStringStrategy.INSTANCE;
```

I'm stumped as to what to look at next.

The full classpath is as follows...

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.10.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.5.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
cxf-core-3.1.11.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.11.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.11.jar
ehcache-2.10.3.jar
gson-2.8.0.jar
guava-20.0.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jaxb2-basics-runtime-1.11.1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
jevv.txt
joda-time-2.9.9.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
mybatis-3.4.4.jar
mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-retry-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar
```

I should state, that at the point I'm getting the error is via AspectJ point around CXF. That makes me feel this might be a class loader issue, but I have only class of the name JAXBToStringStrategy on the class path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of this problem is that the JAXBToStringStategy has changed its definition from the interface to the concrete class.
[image: file compare]

Upgrading the Maven plugin that generates the classes from 0.8.3 TO 0.13.2
fixed the problem.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <generatePackage>${jaxbbeanpackagename}</generatePackage>
                <args>
                    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                    <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                    <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                    <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
                    <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
                    <arg>-XenumValue</arg>
                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.4</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```